# How to set block scope variables in flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

The code below is modified for those who will read the question:

My code looks something like this:

```
private suspend fun decrementCount(): Boolean {
 ...
var isGetCountSuccess: Boolean
val isDecrementCountSuccess = decrementTapCountUseCase(_tapCounter.value)

  functionThatReturnsFlow().onEach {
    if (it in 0..1000) {
       _tapCounter.value = it  
    } else { 
       isGetCountSuccess = false // this doesn't work. how do I make this work?
    }
  }

  return isGetCountSuccess && isDecrementCountSuccess
}
```

the function that is used to return the Flow looks like this:

```
fun functionThatReturnsFlow(): Flow<Int> = flow {
  try {
    preferencesManager.getTapCount().collect { emit(it) }
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.e("Failed to get count from preferences --> $e")
    emit(-1)
  }
}
```

Essentially what happens is that the `decrementTapCountUseCase` updates the tapCounter stored in preferences. and then I get the new value from preferences using the `functionThatReturnsFlow`.

Basically, after about 3 hours of trying to refactor this code, I ended up with what I got above. The logic of the code goes as follows:

1. decrement counter
2. fetch updated count
3. if both of these were successful, play an animation

So far I have this:

1. the decrement counter function returns a boolean signaling whether it was successful or not
2. the fetch new updated count function returns `-1` upon failure. **The only problem is, I do not know how to set the `isGetCountSuccess` variable. Setting it in the onEach function DOES NOT WORK. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?** I cannot use a `.catch` since the flow technically never fails at any point. I just need to set the `isCountSuccess` Boolean based on the flow's value

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense to involve a Flow in this. If you want to fetch one thing, the current value from your preferences, you should call a suspend function that returns that value. It doesn't make sense to get a Flow and iterate all the way through it to find out if the value changed. When a repo returns a Flow, usually it is an infinite flow that can never finish being collected because it monitors the repo for changes indefinitely. A finite flow might be appropriate if running through a series of actions--doesn't apply here.